# Append variable to string in angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

I have an html file which has the following code:

```
 <div class="medium-6 columns page-header__right">
              <div class="md-tab md-tab--tabs md-tab--nav">
                <ul class="md-tab__list right" role="tablist">
                  <li
                    class="md-tab__item"
                    *ngFor="let tab of tabs"
                    role="presentation"
                    [ngClass]="{ 'active current': tab.value === activeTab.value }"
                    (click)="changeActiveTab(tab)"
                    translate-values="{activeTab: $ctrl.activeTab.title}"
                  >
                    <a role="tab">{{ tab.title | translate }}</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
```

I have 3 tabs which on click of it changes the page. The tabs are 'A', 'B' and 'C'. The value of tabs are in '`this.activeTab.title` . I want to append the tab clicked and change the header which is coming from a JSON file. For eg. When 'A' tab is clicked, I want the header to become : `A is clicked`. When 'B' is clicked, it should be `B is clicked`. I have tried adding the variable  My JSON file looks like this:

`header: {{activeTab}} is clicked`

But the above code is not working, the UI shows the header as

`{{activeTab}} is clicked`

**EDIT**
The function to check the selected tab is as shown below:

```
 public changeActiveTab(tab) {
    this.activeTab = tab;
    console.log('activetab', this.activeTab.title)
  }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: show your ts file pls

Comment: `translate-values="{activeTab: $ctrl.activeTab.title}"` the $ctrl is an observable?

Comment: @Anarno due to privacy reasons, I won't be able to add the whole file. I have added the function which checks the selected tab. The console log shows the value that is required to append with the string

Comment: What do you see in console?

Comment: Can you tell us what is your component change detection strategy?

Comment: You can pass the translation param like this: `{{ 'TRANSLATION_ID' | translate:'{ username: "PascalPrecht" }' }}`

Comment: Can you try to switch this :` translate-values="{activeTab: $ctrl.activeTab.title}"`
to that : `[translate-values]="{activeTab: $ctrl.activeTab.title}"`